# Запрос с несколькими разными условиями

Tags: sql

Реально ли сделать одним запросом получение данных с разными условиями типа:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 YEAR).
```

Задача получить несколько, а точно - 4, переменных, хранящие данные за последний год, последний месяц, неделю, день. Все просто, нужно просто менять последнее слово запроса. (`YEAR`,`MONTH`,`WEEK`,`DAY`),

но можно ли вытащить все это одним запросом?

```
SELECT sum(строки) FROM таблица WHERE дата_строки> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одной строкой, 4 колонки:

```
SELECT sum(case_value) Y,
       sum(if(case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 MONTH),case_value,0)) as M,
       sum(if(case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 WEEK),case_value,0)) as W,
       sum(if(case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 DAY),case_value,0)) as D
  FROM cases
 WHERE case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 YEAR)
```

4я строками, колонка с типом записи и колонка данных:

```
SELECT 'YEAR' P,sum(case_value) Y
  FROM cases WHERE case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 YEAR)
 UNION
SELECT 'MONTH' P,sum(case_value) Y
  FROM cases WHERE case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 MONTH)
 UNION
SELECT 'WEEK' P,sum(case_value) Y
  FROM cases WHERE case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 WEEK)
 UNION
SELECT 'DAY' P,sum(case_value) Y
  FROM cases WHERE case_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 DAY)
```

Comment: Вы следите за моими вопросами? :) Благодарю!

Comment: По моему это уже 3й на который я отвечаю и база ваша со вчерашнего дня под рукой, есть на чем проверять запросы :)